# Content Migrate throwing `MediaInternetNoHandlerException` errors for embedded video fields

Tags: 7, migrations

I am getting the following error on multiple nodes when using the content migrate module on a Drupal 6 to 7 upgrade.

```
Requesting rollback of field "field_video" due to failure to convert record:array (                                                                                                                                                [error]
  &#039;entity_id&#039; =&gt; &#039;5703&#039;,
  &#039;revision_id&#039; =&gt; &#039;36928&#039;,
  &#039;field_video_embed&#039; =&gt; &#039;https://www2.City.urbana.il.us/_Video/_Boards_-_Commissions/Community_Development_Commission/2016/03-22-16.flv&#039;,
  &#039;field_video_value&#039; =&gt; &#039;https://www2.City.urbana.il.us/_Video/_Boards_-_Commissions/Community_Development_Commission/2016/03-22-16.flv&#039;,
  &#039;field_video_provider&#039; =&gt; &#039;zzz_custom_url&#039;,
  &#039;field_video_data&#039; =&gt;
&#039;a:5:{s:35:&quot;emvideo_zzz_custom_url_data_version&quot;;i:1;s:3:&quot;url&quot;;s:110:&quot;https://www2.City.urbana.il.us/_Video/_Boards_-_Commissions/Community_Development_Commission/2016/03-22-16.flv&quot;;s:4:&quot;size&quot;;s:9:&quot;416649450&quot;;s:4:&quot;mime&quot;;s:11:&quot;video/x-flv&quot;;s:4:&quot;type&quot;;s:3:&quot;flv&quot;;}&#039;,
  &#039;field_video_status&#039; =&gt; &#039;1&#039;,
  &#039;field_video_version&#039; =&gt; &#039;0&#039;,
  &#039;field_video_title&#039; =&gt; NULL,
  &#039;field_video_description&#039; =&gt; NULL,
  &#039;field_video_duration&#039; =&gt; &#039;0&#039;,
  &#039;delta&#039; =&gt; &#039;0&#039;,
  &#039;entity_type&#039; =&gt; &#039;node&#039;,
  &#039;language&#039; =&gt; &#039;und&#039;,
  &#039;bundle&#039; =&gt; &#039;meeting&#039;,
)  Cause: exception &#039;MediaInternetNoHandlerException&#039; with message &#039;Unable to handle the provided embed string or URL.&#039; in
/Users/cwahlfeldt/Sites/dev.urbanaillinois.us_D7/sites/all/modules/media/modules/media_internet/media_internet.module:119
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/cwahlfeldt/Sites/dev.urbanaillinois.us_D7/sites/all/modules/emfield/emfield.module(143): media_internet_get_provider(&#039;https://www2.Ci...&#039;)
#1 /Users/cwahlfeldt/Sites/dev.urbanaillinois.us_D7/includes/module.inc(1157): emfield_content_migrate_data_record_alter(Array, Array, Array, NULL)
#2 /Users/cwahlfeldt/Sites/dev.urbanaillinois.us_D7/sites/all/modules/cck/modules/content_migrate/includes/content_migrate.admin.inc(410): drupal_alter(&#039;content_migrate...&#039;, Array, Array, Array)
#3 [internal function]: _content_migrate_batch_process_migrate_data(&#039;field_video&#039;, Object(DrushBatchContext))
#4 /Users/cwahlfeldt/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/commands/core/drupal/batch.inc(149): call_user_func_array(&#039;_content_migrat...&#039;, Array)
#5 /Users/cwahlfeldt/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/commands/core/drupal/batch.inc(99): _drush_batch_worker()
#6 /Users/cwahlfeldt/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/batch.inc(93): _drush_batch_command(&#039;360&#039;)
#7 /Users/cwahlfeldt/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/commands/core/core.drush.inc(1145): drush_batch_command(&#039;360&#039;)
#8 [internal function]: drush_core_batch_process(&#039;360&#039;, &#039;360&#039;)
#9 /Users/cwahlfeldt/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(362): call_user_func_array(&#039;drush_core_batc...&#039;, Array)
#10 /Users/cwahlfeldt/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(214): _drush_invoke_hooks(Array, Array)
#11 [internal function]: drush_command(&#039;360&#039;, &#039;360&#039;)
#12 /Users/cwahlfeldt/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(182): call_user_func_array(&#039;drush_command&#039;, Array)
#13 /Users/cwahlfeldt/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php(92): drush_dispatch(Array)
#14 /Users/cwahlfeldt/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php(61): _drush_bootstrap_and_dispatch()
#15 /Users/cwahlfeldt/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php(16): drush_main()
#16 {main}
```

This happens for hundreds of nodes on the site and they all seem to be using a custom url to a video on a secure server somewhere else. The media module isn't liking the custom urls. I know the videos exist because I can plug the URL ([https://www2.City.urbana.il.us/_Video/*Boards*-_Commissions/Community_Development_Commission/2016/03-22-16.flv](https://www2.City.urbana.il.us/_Video/_Boards_-_Commissions/Community_Development_Commission/2016/03-22-16.flv)) in and the video will download (using chrome).

p.s. I am attempting the migration locally if that has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Is the target field set up to handle urls that end in .flv (flash video format)?

Is this a GUI only migration and what hard and soft dependencies are set up?

I know you can migrate video urls I did thousands of them last year with no issues at all. But I was using coded migration classes not simply relying on the drupal to drupal migration built in classes. I was not doing Drupal to Drupal but some Proprietary CMS to drupal.

So first check that the target field takes the url from the source and makes sense of it. If that works make sure the .flv video format is accepted by the media field and then if all else fails you will have to write code to handle that migration.

Comment: Hey TechnoTim, thanks for responding!

1. Im not sure how to set that up?

2. 
  a. im using the drush content-migrate-fields command but i have used the gui and its the same results. 
  b. not sure what you mean by this?

Comment: Ok, migrations have to be done in order. If there is a media file containing the video, this needs to be migrated before the field referring to it and in the GUI at least and maybe in code you need to mark the media-field with the file migration as a dependency. There are examples of this on the web if you google "drupal migrate media" you should strike lucky.